# Need help query in SQL Server 2008 based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question about SQL Server

Table: `Emp`

```
empid | empidref | Name
------+----------+------
 1    |  NULL    |  a
 3    |   1      |  b
 4    |   2      |  c
 2    | NULL     |  d
 5    | NULL     |  e
 6    | NULL     |  f
 8    |  7       |  g 
 7    | NULL     |  h
10    |NULL      |aa
```

I want to merge `empidref` values in `empid` when `empid` also same value. If `empid` values are available in `empidref` table then same `empidref` values consider as empid and corresponding empidref  name need retrieve if `empid` values not available in `empidref` table then same empid values consider as empid and corresponding name need retrieve

Based on above table I want output like below

```
Empid  | Name
-------+------
1      | b
2      | c
5      | e
6      | f
7      |g
10     |aa
```

Please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e1.empid, COALESCE(e2.Name, e1.Name)
FROM Emp e1 LEFT JOIN Emp e2
    ON e1.empid = e2.empidref
WHERE e1.empidref IS NULL
```

Comment: HI Given above query few off records are missing(not given expected result) empid :5,6,10 records not getting in the out put.we required that records also.please tell me how to achieve this task in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for your requirement.

```
SELECT
 E1.EmpId
,CASE WHEN E2.Name IS NOT NULL
        THEN E2.Name
      ELSE E1.Name
 END AS [Name]
FROM #Emp E1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #Emp E2 ON E1.EmpId = E2.EmpIdRef
WHERE E1.EmpIdRef IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say you can code like this:

```
SELECT empidref AS Empid , Name
FROM Emp
WHERE empidref IS NOT NULL
-- Select empidref where it is not null
UNION ALL
-- Merge it with
SELECT empid , Name
FROM Emp
WHERE empidref IS NULL 
-- Select empid where empidref is null
    AND empid NOT IN    (SELECT empidref 
                         FROM Emp 
                         WHERE empidref IS NOT NULL)
-- And empid is not in previous select
```

Another way is using a `ROW_NUMBER()` like this:

```
SELECT empid, Name
FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE(empidref, empid) as empid, Name, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(empidref, empid) ORDER BY empidref DESC) AS seq
    FROM Emp) t
WHERE seq = 1
```

In above query I said it `COALESCE(empidref, empid)` as when empidref is null then use empid and make a sequence column - from 1 - for each `COALESCE(empidref, empid)` that sorted descending over empidref to come null values after not null values then filter that sequence for `1` because I need just first not null value.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select isnull(empidref,empid) as empid,name  
from emp  where 
empid not in (select empidref from emp  where empidref is not null)
```